# Typescript class getters that validate property presence

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm enjoying a new (to me) pattern of creating data models as classes from api responses as they can have reusable derived logic that shouldn't necessarily be returned from the api.

My issue is having multiple getters that I would like to assert existence of a property when referencing each other (or in fact used in other files) but don't, so I'm wondering what I'm missing or what the better solution is:

```
type TodoResponse = {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
    authors?: string[];
}


class Todo implements TodoResponse {
  userId!: number;
  id!: number;
  title!: string;
  completed!: boolean;
  authors?: string[];

  constructor(todo: TodoResponse) {
    Object.assign(this, todo);
  }

  get hasAuthors(): boolean {
    return Boolean(this.authors?.length);
  }

  get firstAuthor(): string | void {
    if (this.hasAuthors) return this.authors[0]
  // errors with: Object is possibly 'undefined'
  }

  get firstAuthor(): string | void {
    if (this.authors?.length) return this.authors[0]
  // this works but it feels redundant to duplicate logic from other getters
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `this.hasAuthors` be `this.hasAuthors()`?

Comment: @AnindyaDey, no a getter shouldn't called like a regular function.

Comment: Getters can't be used as type guards this way; there's a feature request at [ms/TS#43368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43368).  If you make `hasAuthors` a method instead of a getter you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2aR4W).  Otherwise I don't think this is possible.  Does that fully address your question (and I can write up an answer) or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Looks like the answer I'd have given as well. Please post so I can upvote :-)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, if you post an answer I'd be happy to accept. Nice info on the request, I hope it gets accepted as it would be nice to keep things consistent (function call vs normal property access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is for a check of `todo.hasAuthors` to act as a *type guard* which can be used to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `todo` to something that is known to contain a defined `authors` property.  Unfortunately TypeScript does not currently have a way to achieve this.

---

First, classes cannot be seen to implement [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) types; otherwise you could have `Todo` be assignable to `{hasAuthors: true, authors: string[]} | {hasAuthors: false, authors?: undefined}`.  You could maybe use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to have `Todo` look like this from the *outside*:

```
interface TodoWithAuthors extends TodoResponse {
  hasAuthors: true,
  authors: string[],
  firstAuthor: string
}
interface TodoWithoutAuthors extends TodoResponse {
  hasAuthors: false,
  authors?: undefined,
  firstAuthor: void
}
type Todo = TodoWithAuthors | TodoWithoutAuthors;
const Todo = class Todo implements TodoResponse {
   /* snip, your original impl goes here */
} as new (todo: TodoResponse) => Todo;

const todo = new Todo({
  id: 1, userId: 2, title: "",
  completed: false, authors: Math.random() > 0.99 ? undefined : ["a", "b"]
});
if (todo.hasAuthors) {
  // no compiler errors here
  console.log(todo.authors.join(", ")) // a, b
  console.log(todo.firstAuthor.toUpperCase()) // A
}
```

But from the *inside*, the compiler could not see `this.hasAuthors` as having any effect on `this.authors`.  So this doesn't help you the way you want.

---

TypeScript does have the concept of [*user-defined type guard functions and methods*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), where you can call a `boolean`-returning function or method, and it will act as a type guard on one of its input arguments (or on the `this` context of a method).  So if `hasAuthors` were a method instead of a getter, you could do something like this:

```
class Todo implements TodoResponse {
  userId!: number;
  id!: number;
  title!: string;
  completed!: boolean;
  authors?: string[];

  constructor(todo: TodoResponse) {
    Object.assign(this, todo);
  }

  hasAuthors(): this is { authors: string[], firstAuthor: string } {
    return Boolean(this.authors?.length);
  }

  get firstAuthor(): string | void {
    if (this.hasAuthors()) return this.authors[0] // okay
  }

}
```

By annotating the return type of `hasAuthors()` as `this is { authors: string[], firstAuthor: string }`, I'm saying that a `true` result of `obj.hasAuthors()` will narrow the type of `obj` to something with a defined `string[]` property (and also a defined `firstAuthor` property).  This works inside the implementation of `firstAuthor()`.  It also works outside the class:

```
const todo = new Todo({
  id: 1, userId: 2, title: "",
  completed: false, authors: Math.random() > 0.99 ? undefined : ["a", "b"]
});
if (todo.hasAuthors()) {
  // no compiler errors here
  console.log(todo.authors.join(", ")) // a, b
  console.log(todo.firstAuthor.toUpperCase()) // A
}
```

So, that's great.  Unfortunately there is no analogous user-defined type guard *property* or *accessor method* functionality.  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#43368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43368), whose status is currently "Awaiting More Feedback".  That means they probably won't even consider implementing such a feature unless they hear about some compelling use cases from the community.  If you want to see this happen you might consider going to that issue, giving it a , and explaining why this would be better than the current options.  But even if you do that there's no telling when or even if such a feature would be available.

---

So for now you're kind of stuck.  Either you use redundant type guards of the form `if (this.authors?.length) return this.authors[0]`, or you use type assertions like `if (this.hasAuthors) return this.authors![0]`, or you refactor away from your desired implementation.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgFLIgGwF5oDeooaaALgJ4LoAqA9gCb0BK8C9Yc6AvEaWTQBXbgCcAkowBcaMEKgAjGKIDcAsgEtps+UtXqKG8jhgy45URrABzNSEFpk9KAhPkY2hfXomIYOw4QQuQAFvSicAD8ZhZW1gDaALoBaAC+ApCwiCjoALIwoUz8IAbIOBBwcGgMzGgaLiawYORVNazsnNzFDmQiypIAhDJyisopDlpDOqP69j3kRiZT5pY244JODQUeU14+MH7rZEGFEdFoK3FJdgZkTlwWQsjk4QAUL8wybWyInTAAlN0emQAPIKABWMGeADoKnANNYwO8Qho4AAaChMej-I5pEhzBwhCoAQWCYQir3+MlCqLqVUIaBO5LgMVWCUSGIAZhoIuRSadWXE0kDgaICkJRGA0AAhby+JE0uCwsnhKLQkw2UI4254koEwTWApobm8-nkymCmxoAA+aAAbvQtCKehpOWhkajoUS4GbVZTAWLyBKpYrlac4PEAAyJNAAeljaHoAGsIJQdek9Q4Mw57uZMbU+GAYAB3apY17EfWabQARgxfQk2gATBiFsZTGgAESdtE6zaubbaTm4bgYpmqmS5CChaGiPzMKCUtAAPjQkehAE4N2hIsIwIwYNyi4w0DJ4p2ID2uwpO4kDKltfrXe6PvQvSSVRT-oDK8Dc-t1Xoax3ixMNmWhcFHSRK9O2-OMEwgDEFD7ToAJwICQOYaETXMX1RGhF4AFUEBoUQAGEKhgf14LQYl7wEbNZGgdgcjQAARVFkEI4oDCsdxRGHVAy2YAB1IwQjwqoYAAD3cfdWixH4OC4dBfx6b1JOpUQhBgXsq0ZT8WQuWIbCSPTgRwvlP0tax6KfZplEEugsTEwpgkktAZLkxgFOYJS-mdMgNMMmRhxwUcdXHM4ZCEfdDysDxzJ6Sy8JkB0tDshwqBoYT6DQPg2lciTDJtXKivodzDPWXNyFy-LHHKSo6vqAcmhaXL-JUwLhDEQZhl0MYdUmfqZlxNslhs3F+zcHYZD2eVcSiqIbOufE-06R5njeV8vkUjoVJ-HVQQhKFyFhSoEQVFF0XzbFcQzHVDVq4LwwtNB5oOKU1NFcVJRlOVPo9JUlsidUYE1EJH2BB79Ke40eVwz83suK1bXSk9vpdN0gffH1DIDX6Q2usDVQGKM730mGs0ZKoi1LTD6F2vz9u4QEeFXNobn1GrbvquncorIba3rXrm1bRYO27JKc2cAd3CHEddIM8NJ2nEJZ3nZwl1Xdctx3PcDyPDxTzQc9LwxTsbwprMocEZ8GdxyTDv0-8TEA4DXxJiIIKg14YLg+NGSQlCuDQjDPZSz8CPoYjSIo7hqMDuj9Rh-E1t1UBUiAA)